# Integrating PayPal into my university's CMS

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I work for my university supporting the content management system that handles a majority of the associated websites for the university. I specifically work on the custom projects and I'm trying to integrate PayPal into the CMS.

I have already gotten the Express checkout to mostly work with my sandbox accounts but I can't seem to find any documentation on the javascript library it uses except for a few examples at [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) but it's only a bare bones example.

Also I can't find anything on making a payment for a service using paypal, as in the code I have working asks the customer for a shipping address but I'm trying to set up a payment for a service not a tangible item electronic or otherwise.

I just need the user to fill a form out and submit it which takes the user to the paypal modal to pay the cost and then paypal confirms with us that they paid.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

-Edit:

Am markdown noob

Thanks @Lambart for the tips

Comment: that's a bit broad. try asking a more specific question

Comment: @Lambart there are two specific questions: is there any documentation on the javascript library used for the express checkout other that the bare bones example I linked to and is it possible to set up a payment for a service rather than a product?

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question rather than replying as a comment. In any case, I can't answer your question. I am researching paypal integration myself. But more than anything, your question is probably getting downvoted because it's a single, difficult-to-read paragraph. You included a URL but didn't even turn it into a clickable link. Who's going to bother to copy-and-paste it just to help? That's asking a lot. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - FYI I haven't downvoted your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the checkout library:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout

To not require shipping you can create an experience profile and pass `no_shipping: 1`. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/

This is pretty easy with the javascript paypal button, which lets you add experience options in the `paypal.rest.payment.create` call, in the second parameter:

```
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'production', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

    client: {
        sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
        production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    },

    payment: function() {

        var env    = this.props.env;
        var client = this.props.client;

        return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        }, {
            input_fields: {
                no_shipping: 1
            }
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            // Show a success page to the buyer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

Comment: Thanks @bluepnume that helped a ton, I feel like I can better research what I need to do now. The code you show however does create a json.parse error in checkout.js:10960. The json just cuts off at "...no_shipp" which brought me right back to confused...

Comment: Do you have your code hosted somewhere I could try?

Comment: Well... that is definitely a bug. Let me forward that on to the right people. Good catch!

Comment: Oh good, thanks @bluepnume. I will leave that test page up then. Is there an issue on github I can follow to get updates?

Comment: Hey not sure if you're still watching this -- but the issue is finally fixed on sandbox. Sorry it took so long!